# Diesel Injector Well full of Carbon

Tags: diesel, kia, fuel-injectors, compression, carbon

While looking over my friend's 08 Kia Carnival J3 2.9L Turbo Diesel, I noticed a strange huffing noise.  After removing the decorative engine cover I discovered this:

[image]

This injector well is filled with a hard carbon deposit, while the other three injector wells are relatively clean.  I verified that the huffing noise was coming from this cylinder.  My only guess is that maybe the injector seal is bad or the injector isn't quite screwed in tight enough and is allowing combustion gasses to escape which created the carbon deposit around the injector.  That side of the engine also seems quite oily.  The injector itself seems to be operating correctly, I can hear the clicking and the voltage waveform looks normal as far as I can tell.  I should have done a relative compression test, but didn't think about it while I had the car with me.

Anyone seen something like this before?

Comment: I'd suggest you already know the culprit ... if there's a leak from the combustion chamber, you're going to have the noise you're talking about as well as leaked out combustibles, which means gunk.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 OK, so that sounds like an answer to me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Repeating what I put in comments ...)

I'd suggest you already know the culprit ... if there's a leak from the combustion chamber, you're going to have the noise you're talking about as well as leaked out combustibles, which means gunk. This would be the source of the black looking *stuff* around the injector.

More than likely the seals which go around the injector itself have gone bad and are allowing the nastiness to ooze out into the injector well. Replacing the seals and a good cleanup of the area should prove fruitful.